# Dynamic div height using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs side by side but those divs are inside another div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="maindiv1">
        <div id="subdiv1" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel">
                <div id="head1">
                </div>
                <div id="cont1">
                    <li>a</li>
                    <li>b</li>
                    <li>c</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="maindiv2">
        <div id="subdiv2" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel">
                <div id="head2">
                </div>
                <div id="cont2">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                     <li>4</li>             

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my case i want the two divs #cont1 and #cont2 to grow dynamically and i need to set the same height. That is, both the height of #cont1 and #cont2 should be same

I tried giving "display:flex" but it didnt work.. 
please help me on this

using jQuery i am able to set the heights but i need to set using html and css. Is there any way to do this???

http://fiddle.jshell.net/keshav_1007/1yvbt45b/4/ - here is my fiddle

Note : I have a heading for each div that should also come..!!

CSS :

```
.row {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row;
}
#subdiv1,#subdiv2{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think you should be using LIs without an ol or ul. Second, if you are using flex you can probably strip away a good bit of the containers and bootstrap classes. The markup is needlessly cluttered and using IDs for styling rather than classes is also unnecessary and clutters your styles and markup.

I believe this accomplishes what you are looking for:

CSS:

```
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.list-container{
  display:flex;
  flex: 1 auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow:column;
}
.list-header{
  background-color: red;
}
.stretchy-list{
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 2;
  margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='list-container'>
    <div class='list-header'>
      heading1
    </div>
    <ul class='stretchy-list'>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>d</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='list-container'>
    <div class='list-header'>
      heading2
    </div>
    <ul class='stretchy-list'>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/529h7m1e/)

Answer (score 2):

Make the maindivs flex containers:

```css
#maindiv1, #maindiv2 {
    display: flex;
}
```

This way, the subdivs will be flex items of the maindivs, so they will be stretched vertically to have the same height of the maindivs.

However, there is a problem: you use `display: table-cell`. Therefore, the subdivs will generate an anonymous table parent, so the flex item will be that anonymous parent, instead of the subdivs.

[image]

So you must remove this:

```css
#subdiv1, #subdiv2{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
#maindiv1, #maindiv2 {
  display: flex;
}
#subdiv1,#subdiv2{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="maindiv1">
    <div id="subdiv1" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="head1">
          heading1
        </div>
        <div id="cont1">
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="maindiv2">
    <div id="subdiv2" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="head2">
          heading2
        </div>
        <div id="cont2">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```